# A sequence that avoids both arithmetic and geometric progressions

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

Sequences that avoid arithmetic progressions have been studied, e.g., "Sequences Containing No 3-Term Arithmetic Progressions," Janusz Dybizbański, 2012, [journal link](http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v19i2p15).

I started to explore sequences that avoid both arithmetic and geometric progressions,
i.e., avoid $x, x+c, x+2c$ and avoid $y, c y, c^2 y$ anywhere in the sequence
(not necessarily consecutively).
Starting with $(1,2)$, one cannot extend with $3$ because $(1,2,3)$ forms an
arithemtical progression, and one cannot extend with $4$ because $(1,2,4)$ is a geometric
progression. But $(1,2,5)$ is fine.

Continuing in the same manner leads to the following "greedy" sequence:
$$1, 2, 5, 6, 12, 13, 15, 16, 32, 33, 35, 39, 40, 42, 56, 81, 84, 85, 88,$$
$$90, 93, 94, 108, 109, 113, 115, 116, 159, 189, 207, 208, 222, \ldots$$

This sequence is not in the OEIS.
Here are a few questions:

> **Q1**. What is its growth rate?

[image: Avoiding3Terms]

> **Q2**. Does $\sum_{i=1}^\infty 1/s_i$ converge? (Where $s_i$ is the $i$-th term of the above
>   sequence.)
>
> **Q3**. If it does, does it converge to *e*?
>   *Update*: No. The sum appears to be approximately $2.73 > e$, as per
>   @MichaelStocker and @Turambar.

That is wild numerical speculation. The first 457 terms (the extent
of the graph above) sum to 2.70261.

---

**Addendum**. *11Jul2014*. Starting with $(0,1)$ rather than $(1,2)$ renders
a direct hit on OEIS [A225571](https://oeis.org/A225571).

Comment: Expanding on your numerical data I conclude that Q3 can be answered in the negative.

457th term is 17933 with sum of reciprocals : 2.702607644337383

1000th term is 66102 : 2.718058753659135

but alas, somewhere shortly after that the sum excedes e.

2000 253701 2.7259164358931023.

3000 442429 2.7287027640882804.

Comment: @MichaelStocker: Ah, too bad. But still, if it converges, that would be interesting. Can you guess from your data if it indeed seems to be converging?

Comment: The answer to Q2 is definitely *Yes*, it converges, because even just avoiding arithmetic progressions leads to convergence. Converges to what constant is unclear.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke Really? I may be ignorant here so going out on a  limb, but I don't think $a_n=n\ln n$ is in an arithmetic progression, but the sum of its reciprocals *diverges*.

Comment: @JohnMolokach In fact, when you look at the difference in terms in the OEIS sequence, it looks a lot like OEIS [A006519](https://oeis.org/A006519), which is $O(n\ln(n))$. The sequence talked about in the question is a bit different, but I think asymptotically they'd be the same, meaning the sum of reciprocals diverges. And of course, this is just a heuristic, not a proof.

Comment: Whoops, meant to say the sum of EOIS A006519 is $O(n\ln(n))$

Comment: On the other hand, after looking at it out to $i = 10,000$, the chart of the differences doesn't seem to be as similar to A006519 as I thought. Its peaks grow faster and have a more bell curve distribution around them instead of the recursive characteristics of A006519. At $i = 10,000$, $\ln(s_i)/\ln(i) = 1.679258559$ and generally growing, with the sum of reciprocals around $2.734896156$. So if the "power" keeps generally growing (and doesn't start dropping to 1 after some point), then the sum is below $2.736095249$.

Comment: A225571 has an interesting [graph](https://oeis.org/A225571/graph) with striking jumps near 2000, 4000, and 6000. Can these be explained?

Comment: I'll echo that avoiding arithmetic progressions is not enough to conclude convergence.  This would follow if the Erdos conjecture on arithmetic progressions were known.

Comment: @Rahul This sequence [OEIS A289206](https://oeis.org/A289206) has a similar [graph](https://oeis.org/A289206/graph) though the jumps are at different values

Comment: We don't need something as strong as the Erdos conjecture. The best bound for Roth's theorem are very very close to proving that any subset of positive integers with divergent sum of reciprocals contains infinitely many (nontrivial) 3APs

Comment: @awwalker: I don't know how I concluded that just avoiding arith progressions leads to convergence. I apologize for misleading. But I appreciate the interest in the question!

Answer (score 3):

$\color{brown}{\textbf{HINT}}$

Denote the target sequence $\{F_3(n)\}$ and let us try to estimate the probability $P(N)\}$ that natural number belongs to $\{F_3\}.$

Suppose
$$F_3(1)=1,\quad F_3(2)=2,\quad P(1)=P(2)=P(5) = P(6) = 1,\\ P(3)=P(4)=P(7)=P(8)=0,\tag1$$
$$V(N)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N}P(i),\quad F_3(N) = \left[V^{-1}(N)\right].\tag2$$

Let $P_a(N)$ is the probability that N does not belong to arithmetic progression and $P_g(N)$ is the similar probability for geometric progressions.

Suppose
$$P(N) = P_a(N)P_g(N)).\tag3$$

$\color{brown}{\textbf{Arithmetic Probability estimation.}}$

Suppose
$$P_a(N)=\prod\limits_{k=1}^{[N/2]}P_a(N,k),\tag4$$
where $P_a(N,k)$ is the probability that arithmetic progression $\{N-2k,N-k, N\}$ does not exist for any $j.$ 
Suppose
$$P_a(N,k) = \big(1-P(N-2k)\big)\big((1-P(N-k)\big).\tag5$$

$\color{brown}{\textbf{Geometric Probability estimation.}}$

Suppose
$$P_g(N)=\prod\limits_{k=1}^{\left[\,\sqrt Nn\,\right]}P_g(N,k),\tag6$$
where $P_g(N,k)$ is the probability that geometric progression $\left(\dfrac{N}{k^2}, \dfrac Nk, N\right\}$ with the denominator $k$  does not exist for all $i,j.$

Taking in account that the geometric progression can exist only if $k^2\,| \ N,$ suppose
$$P_g(N,k) = \left(1-\dfrac1{k^2}P\left(\dfrac{N}{k^2}\right)\right)\left(1-P\left(\dfrac{N}{k}\right)\right).\tag7$$

$\color{brown}{\textbf{Common model.}}$

Common model can be simplified to next one,
\begin{cases}
P(N) = 1-\prod\limits_{k=1}^{[N/2-1]}\Big(1-\big(1-P(N-2k)\big)\big(1-P(N-k)\big)\Big)\\
\times\prod\limits_{k=1}^{\left[\sqrt N\right]}\left(1-\left(1-\dfrac1{k^2}P\left(\dfrac{N}{k^2}\right)\right)\left(1-P\left(\dfrac{N}{k}\right)\right)\right)\\[4pt]
P(1)=P(2)=P(5) = P(6) = 1,\quad P(3)=P(4)=P(7)=P(8)=0\\
V(N)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N}P(i),\quad F_3(n) = \left[V^{-1}(n)\right].\tag8
\end{cases}

Looking the solution in the form of
$$\left\{\begin{align}
&P(N)=P_v(N),\quad\text{where}\quad v=\left[\dfrac{N-1 \mod 4}2\right],\\[4pt]
&P_0(N)=
\begin{cases}
1,\quad\text{if}\quad N<9\\
cN^{-s},\quad\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}\\[4pt]
&P_1(N)=
\begin{cases}
0,\quad\text{if}\quad N<9\\
dN^{-t},\quad\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{align}\right.\tag9$$

then
$$\begin{cases}
&P_0(N) =1-&\prod\limits_{k=1}^{[N/4-1]}\Big(1-\big(1-P_0(N-4k)\big)\big(1-P_1(N-2k)\big)\Big)\\
&&\times\Big(1-\big(1-P_1(N-4k-2)\big)\big(1-P_0(N-2k-1)\big)\Big)\\
&&\times\prod\limits_{k=1}^{\left[\sqrt N/2\right]-1}
\left(1-\left(1-\dfrac1{(2k-1)^2}P_0\left(\dfrac{N}{(2k-1)^2}\right)\right)
\left(1-P_1\left(\dfrac{N}{2k-1}\right)\right)\right)\\[4pt]
&&\times\left(1-\left(1-\dfrac1{4k^2}P_1\left(\dfrac{N}{4k^2}\right)\right)
\left(1-P_0\left(\dfrac{N}{2k}\right)\right)\right)\\[4pt]
&P_1(N) = 1- &\prod\limits_{k=1}^{[N/4-1]}\Big(1-\big(1-P_1(N-4k)\big)\big(1-P_0(N-2k)\big)\Big)\\
&&\Big(1-\big(1-P_0(N-4k-2)\big)\big(1-P_1(N-2k-1)\big)\Big)\\
&&\times\prod\limits_{k=1}^{\left[\sqrt N/2\right]-1}
\left(1-\left(1-\dfrac1{(2k-1)^2}P_1\left(\dfrac{N}{(2k-1)^2}\right)\right)
\left(1-P_0\left(\dfrac{N}{2k-1}\right)\right)\right)\\[4pt]
&&\times\left(1-\left(1-\dfrac1{4k^2}P_0\left(\dfrac{N}{4k^2}\right)\right)
\left(1-P_1\left(\dfrac{N}{2k}\right)\right)\right).
\end{cases}\tag{10}$$

Taking in account $(9),$ can be written
$$\begin{cases}
&P_0(N) =1-&\prod\limits_{k=[N/4-2]}^{[N/4-1]}\,c(N-2k-1)^{-s}\prod\limits_{k=1}^{[N/4-3]}\Big(1-\big(1-c(N-4k)^{-s}\big)\big(1-d(N-2k)^{-t}\big)\Big)\\
&&\times\Big(1-\big(1-d(N-4k-2)^{-t}\big)\big(1-c(N-2k-1)^{-s}\big)\Big)\\
&&\times\prod\limits_{k=1}^{\left[\sqrt N/2\right]-1}
\left(1-\left(1-\dfrac1{(2k-1)^2}c\left(\dfrac{N}{(2k-1)^2}\right)^{-s}\right)
\left(1-d\left(\dfrac{N}{2k-1}\right)^{-t}\right)\right)\\[4pt]
&&\times\left(1-\left(1-\dfrac1{4k^2}d\left(\dfrac{N}{4k^2}\right)^{-t}\right)
\left(1-c\left(\dfrac{N}{2k}\right)^{-s}\right)\right)\\[4pt]
&P_1(N) = 1- &\prod\limits_{k=[N/4-2]}^{[N/4-1]}\,c(N-2k)^{-s}\prod\limits_{k=1}^{[N/4-3]}\Big(1-\big(1-d(N-4k)^{-t}\big)\big(1-(N-2k)^{-s}\big)\Big)\\
&&\Big(1-\big(1-(N-4k-2)^{-s}\big)\big(1-d(N-2k-1)^{-t}\big)\Big)\\
&&\times\prod\limits_{k=1}^{\left[\sqrt N/2\right]-1}
\left(1-\left(1-\dfrac1{(2k-1)^2}d\left(\dfrac{N}{(2k-1)^2}\right)^{-t}\right)
\left(1-c\left(\dfrac{N}{2k-1}\right)^{-s}\right)\right)\\[4pt]
&&\times\left(1-\left(1-\dfrac1{4k^2}c\left(\dfrac{N}{4k^2}\right)^{-s}\right)
\left(1-d\left(\dfrac{N}{2k}\right)^{-t}\right)\right).
\end{cases}\tag{11}$$

Model $(11)$ should be checked theoretically and practically, but it gives the approach to the required estimations.

The next steps are estimation of parameters $$c,d,s,t$$ and using of obtained model.

Comment: @Joseph O'Rourke Approximation can be changed, but parametrization is actual.

Answer (score 3):

Since both @awwalker and @mathworker21 mentioned Erdős' conjecture, and because
a paper discussing this conjecture was just published, I thought I would mention it:

> **Erdős Conjecture** (1940s or 1950s). If $A \subset \mathbb{N}$ 
>   satisfies $\sum_{n \in A} \frac{1}{n}= \infty$, then
>   $A$ contains arbitrarily long arithmetic progressions.

In

- Grochow, Joshua. "New applications of the polynomial method: The cap
  set conjecture and beyond." *Bulletin of the American Mathematical
  Society*, Vol.56, No.1, Jan. 2019,

he says:

> "It remains open even to prove that a set $A$ satisfying the hypothesis contains $3$-term arithmetic progressions."